# How to get marker position (x,y) AR.js

Tags: javascript, aframe, ar.js, jsartoolkit

How can i get the marker position in ARjs ?

Example: when the marker found, i wanna know what is his position(X,Y) at screen.

I tried to use `getBoundingClientRect()` but it does not work with Markers

My issue: I have 4 markers and they have a sequence like (1,2,3,4) and if this sequence is wrong as (1,3,2,4) the system have to identity where  is wrong. So if the marker 1 has positionX = 10 the next marker have to be in positionX = 11.

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Project AR-JS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <script src='index.js'></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Paaji+2:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/3.0.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>



        <a-scene arjs='debudUIEnabled: false;'>

            <a-marker id="letraU" preset="pattern" type="pattern" url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FelippeAlves/project-words-AR/master/pattern-marker_U.patt">

            </a-marker>
            <a-marker id="letraR" preset="pattern" type="pattern" url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FelippeAlves/project-words-AR/master/pattern-marker_R.patt">

            </a-marker>
            <a-marker id="letraS" preset="pattern" type="pattern" url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FelippeAlves/project-words-AR/master/pattern-marker_S.patt">

            </a-marker>
            <a-marker id="letraO" preset="pattern" type="pattern" url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FelippeAlves/project-words-AR/master/pattern-marker_O.patt">

            </a-marker>
        </a-scene>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is in A-Frame ( with AR.js):

We can write a separate component and attach it to an entity element in A-Frame scene: The .tick() handler will get the positions updated every frame and use Three.js get the marker positions values as Three.js Vector3 Object for A-Frame entities and find distance using .distanceTo() method.

Refer: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.distanceTo

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("marker-distance", {
    tick: function () {
        this.markerDistance()
    },
    markerDistance: function () {
        var marker1Pos, marker2Pos

        var marker1 = document.querySelector("#letraU")
        var marker2 = document.querySelector("#letraR")

        marker1Pos = new THREE.Vector3();
        marker1.object3D.getWorldPosition(marker1Pos);

        marker2Pos = new THREE.Vector3();
        marker2.object3D.getWorldPosition(marker2Pos);

        //distance
        this.d = marker1Pos.distanceTo(marker2Pos);
        console.log("distance" + this.d)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

### Jsartoolkit5

**[AR.js](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js)** is based internally on **[jsartoolkit5](https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5)**. If you want to retrieve the position (the center of the marker) you can easily do with an event listener. In jsartoolkit5 supposed that you have initialized the **ARController** and you have an instance of it -> arController:

```js
        arController.addEventListener('getMarker', function(ev) {
            console.log('marker pos: ', ev.data.marker.pos);
            });
```

this is valid for a Pattern Marker.

### AR.js

In case of **AR.js** after you create a new instance of **ArToolkitSource**:

```js
    var arToolkitSource = new THREEx.ArToolkitSource({

            sourceType : 'webcam',
        })
```

listen the incoming data for the **Pattern** (or **Barcode**) Marker in the **onReady()** function:

```js
    arToolkitSource.init(function onReady(){

      console.log(arToolkitContext.arController);
        if( arToolkitContext.arController !== null ){
          arToolkitContext.arController.addEventListener('getMarker', function(ev) {
          console.log('marker pos: ', ev.data.marker.pos);
          });
        }
    })
```

you will listen data in the console.

#### Additional informations

Note if you want retrieve the data for other type of markers use this listeners:

**getMultiMarker** for multi Markers

**getMultiMarkersSub** for subordinates Multi Markers

**getNFTMarkers** for NFT markers ( attention no pos for this type of marker !! )

#### Working Example

Take look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kalwalt/888f3b0463ef7d03a90466640fc2987f)

Comment: i tried it but did not work `var markerLetraU = document.getElementById('letraU'); var arToolkitSource = new THREEx.ArToolkitSource({
        sourceType : 'webcam',
    });
    arToolkitSource.init(function onReady(){

        console.log(arToolkitContext.markerLetraU);
          if( arToolkitContext.markerLetraU !== null ){
            arToolkitContext.markerLetraU.addEventListener('marketFound', function(ev) {
            console.log('marker pos: ', ev.data.marker.pos);
            });
          }
      })`

Comment: it doesn't work because markerLetraU is not an ARController. i will add a link to a gist, when i have a bit of time.

Comment: how can i create an ARController ?

Comment: I added the gist, but i see that you changed your question, you didn't asked for the aframe part, you were generic, Anyway the codebase is Three.js based so it is possible to do the same for aframe-ar.js. If you have problems i can help on this too.

Comment: Thaks for u help, but i tried to use your code, but it does not work. I'll explain better my issue

Comment: I will provdie an example with aframe, i understand that can be more difficult to get the same result.

Comment: Thank's for you help, i find out the answer